# C++ Seperate Include and Source directory and #Include

Tags: c++, build, msbuild, makefile, project

Currently in my application I just have a single source tree

```
MyApp/Source
|-Precompiled.hpp
|-Precompiled.cpp
|-Thing.hpp
|-Thing.cpp
|-Main.cpp
|-Component
| |-ComponentThing.hpp
| |-ComponentThing.cpp
| |-...
|-ComponentB
| |-ComponentBThing.hpp
| |-...
|-PluginCandiate
| |-PluginThing.hpp
| |-PluginThing.cpp
| |-...
...
```

However I want to make a plugin system (so that less stuff is part of the core application with clear boundaries), so many of those .hpp files I want to move to a separate Include\MyApp tree. So the new tree might look like:

```
MyApp/Include/MyApp
|-Thing.hpp
|-Component
| |-ComponentThing.hpp
| ...
|-ComponentB
| |-ComponentBThing.hpp

MyApp/Source
|-Precompiled.hpp
|-Precompiled.cpp
|-PrivateThing.hpp
|-PrivateThing.cpp
|-Component
| |-ComponentThing.cpp
| |-...
|-ComponentB
| |-...
...

Plugins/PluginCandiate/Source
|-PluginThing.hpp
|-PluginThing.cpp
...
```

Now with the current way, I just have "Source" on my include path. This means for example in `ComponentThing.cpp` I can just do say:

```
#include "Precompiled.hpp"
#include "ComponentThing.hpp"
#include "ComponentOtherThing.hpp"
#include "ComponentB/ComponentBThing.hpp"
```

Since the current directory is always first on the include path. However if I split my public include directory and source directory, that is not the case any more. I could put Include/Myapp/ on the include path, but Id still need the full component path for everything.

Is there a simple way to avoid that (with MSVC MSBuild and Linux make files), or is it standard practice to just have the full #includes? Or is there something else people normally do (e.g. I considered a post-build step to "export" a listed public header set out of the main source tree)?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by : "I could put Include/Myapp/ on the include path, but Id still need the full component path for everything"?

Comment: So for say ComponentThing.cpp I wouldn't need some include crap like "../../Include/MyApp/Component/ComponentThing.hpp", but I would still need "Component/ComponentThing.hpp" rather than just "ComponentThing.hpp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can just add the path to your new include folder and just `#include "filename.h"`
The alternative is to include the relative path from a path in the include path.

e.g. if you have the following directory tree:

```
+ MyApp
  - file.c
  - file.h
  + Plugins
    + Include
    - pluginheader.h
```

any `#include` in file.c could be either relative:

```
#include "Plugins/Include/pluginheader.h"
```

or you could add `./Plugins/Include` to your include path and just use

```
#include "pluginheader.h"
```

(you don't have to specify the full path, just the relative path from the working directory)

edit:
This is one of those things you can easilly try yourself, and I think this is what you were asking based on your comment:

`./file.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "module/function.h"
int main()
{
  int sum;
  myStruct orange;
  myStruct_insert(&orange, 5, 6);
  sum = myStruct_sum(&orange);
  printf("%d",sum);
  return 0;
}
```

`./module/function.h`:

```
typedef struct{
    int one;
    int two;
}myStruct;

void myStruct_insert(myStruct *apple, int one, int two);

int myStruct_sum(myStruct *apple);
```

`./module/function.c`:

```
#include "function.h"
void myStruct_insert(myStruct *apple, int one, int two)
{
  (*apple).one = one;
  (*apple).two = two;
}

int myStruct_sum(myStruct *apple)
{
  return (*apple).one+(*apple).two;
}
```

I compiled this with `gcc file.c ./module/function.c` (no include path added).  It compiles without errors and performs correctly:

```
$ gcc file1.c module/function.c
$ ./a
11
$
```

So the answer to your question is yes, it will include headers in the same folder as your code the compiler is currently working on.  Or at least it will for GCC.  MSVC etc may have different behaviours.

However it's better to specify explicity.  It's more verbose but less prone to mixups with similarly named headerfiles.

Comment: For sure, but this assumes every module only has a flat directory, which is not what I am talking about, I am also talking about things including stuff in their "own" directory, not cross component/module includes (where ModuleX/ComponentX/ThingX.hpp makes sense, allthough wiout that nasty /Include/)

Comment: @FireLancer added a worked example that I think captures your question better.